# Como "capturar" uma transmissão de stream por IP usando HTML 5

Tags: html5, html5-video

Estou usando o DVB viewer para transmitir sinal de TV pela rede. Usando, por exemplo, o VLC, eu "pego" o fluxo de rede e tenho a transmissão.
Gostaria de saber como fazer isso usando o HTML. Eu tentei simplesmente criar o player e no `src` colocar o IP, mas não deu certo.

Comment: De uma olhada no projeto [stream-m](https://github.com/vbence/stream-m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui resolver assim, espero que ajude alguém no futuro.

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org" version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"  width="1024" height="768" id="vlc" loop="yes" autoplay="yes" target="http://000.000.000.000:9999/"></embed>
```